# Display Data from Table where Data is not In other Table with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this.

[image]

and a table like this

[image]

My question is this. How can I display data from table2 that is not on table1? on a date basis for example.

[image]

and also how can I include the date?

what I mean sir is how can I display the data from table2 that is not in 1 table1? for example `BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE` are not in table1 only `AAA` on date `1/1/2018`

Comment: The logic by which you arrive at your output is not clear to me.

Comment: what I mean sir is how can I display the data from table2 that is not in 1 table1? for example if `BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE` are not in table1 only `AAA` on date `1/1/2018`

Comment: Can you create a sql fiddle for us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate all the possible rows using `cross join` and then weed out the ones that don't exist:

```
select n.name, d.date
from table2 n cross join
     (select distinct date from table1) d left join
     table1 t1
     on n.name = t1.name and d.date = t1.date
where t1.name is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*,b.*,
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b
Where a.Name <>b.Name
```

Try the above query. If this does not work, please provide a sqlfiddle and we wil improve it.